# How to sort/draw pseudo-3D buildings so as they don't visually overlap

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, drawing

I have vector data for buildings on my map and want them to appear extruded, depending on known height.

I know this is a common task, but i didn't find any satisfying solution.

I saw realization in [mapnik](http://mapnik.org), they use simple sort by minimum Y of all vertices in a polygon. As result, most are drawn right, but some are still overlapped (about 2-3%).

[image: Buildings overlap if sorted just by minimum Y]

In most cases it is enough just to sort buldings well (somehow?) and draw them in appropriate sequence (for above case this sequence would be 3-2-1).

In more complex cases, when polygons are concave and too close to each other, every wall and cap (roof) should be drawn separately (see below).

[image]

UPDATED:

So, there are two kinds of segments to draw: walls and caps. Wall segments are easy to order (by minimum Y). I can't figure out how to order caps.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're always looking at the buildings from above, wouldn't the caps always be in front of the walls? If the caps are all at the same height, then they should never overlap would be order-independent among themselves.

Comment: @Alan no, in common cases there is different height, so it's not just easy

Comment: Ahh, well if you have different height buildings then that changes things.  The general case solution is to use z-buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of straight walls it is easy to sort them by depth. Consider just their bases which are straight line segments. Note that each line divides the plane in two parts, one of them is closer to the viewer and the other is farther. For any segment A, call the closer part A+ and the farther part A-. Now, for any two segments A and B, at least one of the propositions holds:

1. A lies entirely in B+
2. A lies entirely in B-
3. B lies entirely in A-
4. B lies entirely in A+
5. One segment is parallel to the line of sight and the other is entirely to the left or entirely to the right of it
6. A and B intersect

In cases 1 and 3, B should be drawn before A (A may occlude B, but B may not occlude A); in cases (2) and (4) A before B; in case 5, it doesn't matter; and 6 should not occur for normal walls.

You can now do a topological sort of the walls, and draw them from furthest to closest.

As for roofs, this is not possible for concave buildings, since a part of the roof can be obscured by a wall which obscures another part of that same roof. Imagine a low U-shaped building, visible from its side, with a tall tower in the middle of the U. The tower will both obscure and be obscured by the U-roof, so in whatever order you draw them, the picture will be wrong.

So you will have to subdivide concave roofs into convex polygons. Then it should be easy to sort them together with the walls, along the same principles.

A totally another method is to use a Z-buffer, which frees you from thinking about the order. It is my impression that you can get Z-buffer on the lowest of the low-powered cell phone graphic cards these days.

Comment: thank you for clarifying about roofs tesselation, but still trying to understand your algorithm. Shouldn't just the wall with lower point  be drawn later (in case of straight walls)?

Comment: So, I've tested my previous assumption, and it is not right. Though, I didn't get what exactly do you compare saying "A lies entirely in B+"? Sorry for such unawareness. I feel you're right, but can't reach your point.

Comment: A straight line A divides the ground plane in two half-planes. Suppose the viewer looks directly from south to north. If the wall goes along the meridian, then there are no A+ or A- half-planes, only the left and the right half-planes (case 5). In all other cases there is "more southern" half-plane (not obscured by the wall) which we call A+, and "more northern" (partly obscured by the wall) which we call A-.

Comment: Oh and I mean *segment* B lies entirely in A+ or A- (which is to say, it doesn't cross the *line* A). Look at this configuration: `—/`. The slanted *line* divides the plane in two half-planes, and the horizontal *segment* lies entirely in one that faces away from the viewer. We can use this fact to establish the order: the horizontal line is farther away. The horizontal *line* also divides the plane in two half-planes, but the slanted *segment* crosses the horizontal line and hence lies in both half-planes induced by the horizontal segment, so this fact cannot be used to establish the order.

Comment: yes! I've got it, thank you! Now, about the roofs, okay, I have only convex ones. So now, how to compare roofs with other roofs and wall segments, considering their different heights?

Comment: Your picture shows many non-convex roofs too. But anyway, if your buildings are convex, then you can treat the entire building as a line segment. Again, suppose the viewer faces directly to the north. Consider the leftmost and the rightmost meridians that touch the building. Use the two touching points as segment endpoints. If there's more than one touching point at either side (e.g. the wall goes along the meridian) use any of these points. Sort the building as you would sort the line segments. Then draw the whole buildings one by one from farthest to nearest. The height is not important!